# How do I use a ListView tool to list my activity classes in Eclipse (Android) within an activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, listview

I am making an app that shows a list of campfire songs, and currently all I can see on my app is a list of all the songs and when clicked on, they open up another activity. The next activity that is opened looks how I want it to, but the list of songs on the first activity (menu) only shows a list with no formatting around it or any images or buttons that I have specified in the XML. - I haven't linked these up in the code as they stop the list from appearing at all.

Here is my Java file for Menu.java:

```
package com.lmarshall1995.scoutsongs;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] = {"......"};

    String items[] = {"......"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String song_activity = classes[position];
        try{
        Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("com.lmarshall1995.scoutsongs." + song_activity);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my XML file for menu.xml that I would like the list to be put in (@+id/list):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SelectSong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ic_launcher"
        android:text="@string/SelectSong"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ic_launcher"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" >

    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_launcher"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_button_selected"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:src="@drawable/exit_button_selected"
        android:contentDescription="@string/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I was wondering if someone could help me turn what I think is the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 into my list (@+id/list) from my menu.xml file. Any suggestions?
Thanks,
From
Laurence =]

Comment: If you have one activity per song, that's very poor app design. Why don't you use a single SongActivity and pass in (by intent-extra) which song you want it to display?

Comment: @323go, do you reckon you could explain how I could go about doing that? Would that be a List Fragment?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to begin. This is so basic, if you google Android Intents and Intent extras, you should be able to work it out.

Comment: @323go I've Googled around, and the best I can find is by looking [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) but that doesn't really explain how to make multiple activities into one activity, I see where you are coming from, I would like to do it, and it does seem pretty basic but I need some source code to look at, and there is none.

Comment: @323go I have written what you are suggesting as another question, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220019/how-can-i-make-multiple-activities-be-in-one-activity-changing-only-strings). Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setContentView(R.layout.menu)` in `onCreate` before calling `setListAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be something simple like this. It worked. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom adapter to do that, create a class tha extens BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter and use that instead of the simple android adapter.
See [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) a tutorial.

Comment: Just a note on that, if the custom xml follows the naming conventions of the normal android layout (ie. having a pair of textviews with the ids of "@android:id/text1" and "@android:id/text2"), then he can just plug that xml into the normal adapter and it would work.

Comment: I originally thought this too, but then found on the internet that I could use "@android:id/list" instead of "@id/list") my case. :-)